# jenkins merge multiple branches to "integration-branch" branched from master

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Can you please let me know if there a way to create a branch newbranch1 from master in git and merge multiple branches B1, b2, b3 into newbranch1 in jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that should be easy (moreso if you're using Linux as the OS).

Use the Git SCM plugin to configure the repo. Then you'll want to use the shell plugin and just run the git commands that you're describing:

```
git fetch origin    #not strictly necessary
git checkout -b newbranch1 origin/master

git merge B1 b2 b3

# it would be wise to put some smarts in here... $? && git push maybe?
git push origin master
```

Of course, git & Jenkins can only do so much. If there are conflicts that git can't work out then this job isn't going to do much for you as you'd need to perform the merge manually.

Comment: Thank you @acanby. I am on windows. Since git comes with shell, I configured jenkins to run gits's shell and ran the script as you a have mentioned.

Comment: inorder to run git commands, one should set env varable HOME. I used envinject plugin to do this.